# Is chkdsk ntfs suppose to get to stage 5 of 5 and start up again?

Tags: ntfs, chkdsk

I need help badly, I was getting "blue screen" several times and was told by Windows to do a NTFS CHKDSK.

I checked both areas for checking and fixing.  This was 4 days ago and the checking continues.  I cannot stop it.  I have a very large C Drive, probably 3Gb. Is it taking a long time because it is such a large C drive and is it suppose to keep repeating?

I do not know DOS commands and very green when it comes to understanding what others sources are telling me to do.  **Please if you can tell me how I can save my hard drive?**  I have files backed up but have some important software that cannot find the keys.  So it is important to get Windows back.

Okay, after it get to the 5 of 5, it shuts down, restart, windows comes up, get to window page without the icons then it shut down and start the process.  **Is it possible to restore Windows or should I take in for repairs?**

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run your Windows in recovery/safe mode by holding F8 or Ctrl in the first few seconds of loading?
Then if it's not rebooted, try to run Scandisk again.
Otherwise what happens if you cancel your CHKDSK using Control-C? Is your system is booting correctly?
Otherwise you have to use boot your computer using your Windows CD and try to run CHKDSK from here, it shouldn't crash. If nothing works, then try to boot your Windows from CD again and choose to Repair your system.